# Use "rm dir -rf" instead of "rm -rf dir" on OSX

Tags: macos, shell

Commands use fixed order of options in OSX terminal. So, for instance, I must use `rm -rf name`, instead of `rm name -rf`, which is much more convenient for me (for example I can add all names first, then see whether I have directories there and need to add `-r`).

Is there a way to allow OSX-commands more general syntax?

I am not sure that this is possible, but, for example, I wonder about some preprocessing of shell commands with ... python program, which will reformat options and call appropriate command. But I unfamiliar with python and don't know how to make such a program run each time I write a command.

Comment: most *nix commands have "fixed order" of options (as you say), in that you must supply the options before a list of other arguments, this is not unique to OSX.

Comment: @Donovan, yes, but this does not discard my question. Futhermore some of *nix allow to use rm dir -rf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OSX has BSD implementation of common UNIX tools. These are more strict than the GNU implementations you find in a typical Linux. So not only for `rm`, but for example `ls`, `mkdir`, the flags must come before filename arguments in OSX. I find that pretty annoying too.

Probably you can install GNU version of these tools. In the worst case, you can download the source code and build them. Put them in a new dedicated directory, and put prepend that directory to your `PATH`.

I don't think there is another way. You cannot change the behavior of the BSD tools like that.

**UPDATE**

As [@bdesham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371228/bdesham) pointed out, you can install `coreutils` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to get the GNU implementations. I can confirm that with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) too.

Comment: If you install `coreutils` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), you can then add `PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` to your `.login` or whatever and the GNU commands will take precedence over the built-in ones.

Answer (score 1):

Each Unix/Linux command determines the required order or grouping of arguments and options for itself. There is no general way to override that.

However, the Bash (Bourne-again shell, long story...) shell -- i.e. command-line interpreter -- with which you interact when the Terminal window opens, supports command-line history and editing. The editing uses key combinations from one of two widely used text editors which have  been available on Unix/Linux platforms for 30 years or more. The default editor emulation is from an editor called Emacs. Using the editor, you can easily change commands before submitting them or retrieve previous commands to use as a template for a new command.

One quick-reference to the default editing commands can be found at:

[List of default Mac OS X command-line editing bash keyboard shortcuts](http://maymay.net/blog/2007/07/18/list-of-default-mac-os-x-command-line-editing-bash-keyboard-shortcuts/)

In fact, there is quite a lot to the Bash shell -- or any Linux/Unix command-line interpreter for that matter. For the complete reference manual, see:

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Also, on Mac OS X, Linux, or Unix, the "man" command will display help documentation for nearly all available commands as well as numerous other features of the base operating system. To learn more, enter the following at the command prompt:

```
man man
```